# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header too wide

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to assign the width of each of the DataGridTemplateColumn in a DataGrid using "*".

```
<DataGrid  Name="Mapping" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1"                   
    ItemsSource="{Binding Information.Signals}" 
             SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" FontSize="10" 
             RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" BorderThickness="1"   
             EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll ="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
             CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True"  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}" 
                                CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="True" SortMemberPath="Name"                                                                           
                                Width="6*"
                                >
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" 
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyTemplate}" 
                                CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="True"  SortMemberPath="SelectedProperty"                                    
                                Width="4*">
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And the ColumnTemplates are similar to this one

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" MinWidth="280" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Calibri"  
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

When the Window is Maximized the scaling works fine. What happens is that when it is not Maximized, the Header is almost 3 Monitors wide, like 3000 pixels.

If I set the width to a fixed value everything is fine as well.
Could anyone suggest me how to tackle this problem? I would like to use the relative scaling using "*"

UPDATE:
The WPF Project is using MahApps controls, so I am not sure if this is the reason.

Comment: did you set the window height and width? If the window is not maximized, it will follow the height and width value.

Answer (score 1):

Width and Height when applied using "*" are measured on count of "1".
So whenever you divide your screen it has to be divided such as one full part is being divided.

Using 4* and 6* is incorrect. Use 0.4* and 0.6* instead, which sums to one.

Comment: I tried this and apparently it did not help. Do you think that the fact I am using the DataGrid from MahApps could be the problem?

Comment: I executed the code you provided and it works fine. I think the problem could be with MahApps. Remove MahApps controls and use the normal ones and try it.

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: I removed the MahApp Controls, but it was not helping. Did you try it on Multi Monitor Setup? I am thinking where else would I have messed up...

Comment: Do you think this is normal behaviour of DataGrid? which means I should just drop it, I dont think users of my App will like it, the app spans across 3 monitors in non maximized.